# SQL Update else Insert not working

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm trying to update a users details inside an SQL database, however if a row of that user dose not exist, I need to create one for that user (Only one per user)
It's just not updating nor inserting.
Here is the following script.

```
$sql = "IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM user_details WHERE user_id = $user_id)
UPDATE user_details SET work = $work, education = $education, location = $location, relationship = $relationship, phone = $phone, email = $email, website = $website, language = $language, skill = $skill, tumbkr = $tumblr, instagram = $instagram, skype = $skype, facebook = $facebook, youtube = $youtube, twitter = $twitter, about = $about, user_id = $user_id WHERE user_id = $user_id
ELSE
INSERT INTO user_details (work, education, location, relationship, phone, email, website, language, skill, tumblr, instagram, skype, facebook, youtube, twitter, about, user_id)";
    $q = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $q->execute();
```

Comment: you should learn about prepared statements

Comment: Look up [insert...on duplicate key update](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) syntax.

Comment: read about merge statement

Comment: I will be doing a prepared statement, however it will take a long time to write. I'm just trying to get this base script working

Comment: Prepared statements do _not_ take long to write. You've already got 90% of it.

Comment: Yes, I've read about merge and insert on duplicate but nothing seems to be working. I have user_id as unique key too but not auto increment

Comment: As long as it's the primary key (i.e. unique) then insert on duplicate key will work. If it doesn't you should be asking why that isn't working. Your current SQL is... not great, and broken.

Comment: By the way, in general, an `UPDATE` statement without a `WHERE` condition is probably not going to do what you expect it to.

Comment: I know its not great, Its most likely because i'm getting frustrated with researching and not finding any help after constantly writing out more and more code.

Comment: @jeroen Have a look at the insert too, it's missing any insert values.

Comment: @JonStirling Yes, I think *... not great, and broken* is the right term :-)

Answer (score 1):

Do as below:

`INSERT INTO table_name (field1,field2) VALUES (val1,val2)
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE field_name=VALUE;`

Comment: Without any explanation as to what this statement does and what requirements the statement needs to satisfy, this answer is close to useless.

Comment: code is easy so, I think not required explanation.

Comment: It does need explanation because the above code will not work unless ecrtain specific requirements are met. Anyway, this question has been answered manay times already on SO.

Comment: so, in this case edit my answer with proper explanation... :)

Comment: Pointless, the duplicate topic lists all possible solutions with links to the mysql documentation.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I shall give it a go with my values and hope for the best :)